# What is the conditions to update the table in DVR algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, networking, routes, graph-algorithm, bellman-ford

I was reading DVR algorithm from [TCP/IP Protocol Suite](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/TCP_IP_Protocol_Suite.html?id=JhRLAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y&hl=en) by [Behrouz A. Forouzan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behrouz_A._Forouzan).

Here I read that if the incoming record say **R** from some router say **A** to the table of router say **C** is not present in the table of **C** so it will update its table with that new entry.

And if the record is present so it checks if the cost of path reaching towards the destination of lower than it's current cost in its table. If it is, so it will update its table with next felid of the table as the source router address and cost as the `costFromSourceRouter + 1`.

Then I read this algorithm pseudocode.

```
Distance_Vector_Algorithm( )
{
    // At startup
    for(i = 1 to N)                 // N is number of ports
    {
        Tablei.dest = address of the attached network
        Tablei.cost = 1
        Tablei.next = ----          // Means at home
        Send a record R about each row to neighbor

    } // end of for loop

    //  Updating

    repeat(forever)
    {
        wait for arrival of a record R from a neighbor
        Update(R, T)                // Call update module
        for(i = 1 to N)             // N is the current table size
        {
            Send a record R about row to each neighbor
        }
    } // end repeat
}// end Distance_Vector_Algorithm

Update (R, T)
{
    Search T for a destination matching the one in R
    if(destination is found in row i)
    {
        if(R.cost + 1 < Ti.cost or R.next == Ti.next)
        {
            Ti.cost = R.cost + 1
            Ti.next = Address of sending router
        }
        else    discard the record      // No change is needed
    }
    else
        // Insert the new router
        {
            TN+1.dest = R.dest
            TN+1.cost = R.cost +1
            TN+1.next = Address pf sending router
            Sort the table according to destination address
        }
} // end of update module
```

In this screenshot **R** is the record sent by the source router and **T** is the table of the receiver router. In the `Update` function the nested `if` has two conditions.

1. `R.cost + 1 < Ti.cost`. That is, updation will take place when the `receivedCost + 1` is lesser than the `currentCost`, which is obvious.
2. `R.next == Ti.next`. That is, updation will take place if the next field of both the received record is same as that of the current record in the table.

**Can someone explain me this second condition?** I do manual updates in the sample tables for a sample circuit, and the second condition is leading to the new path which has a higher cost than the previous one.

Sample Network

[image: Sample Network]

Tables:

```
**Router A (destination, cost, next)**
net1 1 -
net2 1 -
net3 1 -


**Router B (destination, cost, next)**
net1 2 A
net2 1 -
net4 1 -

**Router C (destination, cost, next)**
net1 2 A
net3 1 -
net4 1 -
```

So when **B** is exchanging `net1` record with **C** so both have same next field which is **A**. So according to the above algorithm (if it is right) so C will update its table as

```
**Router C (destination, cost, next)**
net1 3 B
net3 1 -
net4 1 -
```

> So the update makes a negative change in the table. How algorithm (`if` condition for updation) worked in that scenario?

Comment: Ok, it will take some mintes. I'll do for you.

Comment: Done @iBug. I have edited my question. Take a look.

Comment: How is it related to Bellman-Ford algorithm? It looks, to me, like a variant of Dijkstra.

Comment: This is the DVR algorithm, which uses Bellman-Ford algorithm to find the shortest path. First, it marked the cost of its neighbors than infinity for non-neighbors, then each node exchange information with one another to find the best path to each node.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-vector_routing_protocol